# how to delete the ^M in the end of lines?

Tags: vi

i am working in xp+gvim.

```
                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb^M
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2^M
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4^M
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4^M
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4^M
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1^M
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2^M
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
```

I  get the  data  by the command

```
:r  !sort  /cygdrive/c/workspace/accountant.txt
```

i want to delete the **^M**.

1.method1

```
:%s/\^M$//g  
pattern not found ^M
```

0d0a  is  ^M, why `:%s/\x0d0a//g` can not run ?

2.method2

```
dos2unix  /cygdrive/c/workspace/accountant.txt
dos2unix: converting file /cygdrive/c/workspace/accountant.txt to Unix format.
```

nothing  changed when i open the target file.

3.mehtod3

```
:!s/.\{2}$//g
```

method3 is ok.

Comment: :%s/^v^M$//g with ^ meaning <control> So: control-V plus control-M .

Comment: same problem as `:%s/\^M$//g` , pattern not found ^M

Comment: aside from vim you could use `dos2unix` to remove the \r chars (displayed as ^M)

Comment: , or use `tr -d \\015` (from the shell; outside vi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use `:%s/\r$//` - "for all lines, replace a carriage-return at the end of the line with nothing".

Answer (score 1):

I have this snippet in my `.vimrc`

```
command! KillControlM :normal :%s/<C-V><C-M>//e<CR><C-O><CR>
```

You can use it by just typing `:KillControlM` in command mode :)